# Can't run a defined function in a Python class

Tags: python

I'm making an app for a photobooth and to test the functions, I called the function called takephoto just after building the interface in the code, but the console has no printed TESTING. What can be causing the issue to appear?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import Video
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import datetime
import time

class MyPhotoBoothApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.takephoto
        global fl
        fl = FloatLayout()
        fl = FloatLayout(size=(300, 300))
        global buttonstart
        buttonstart = Button(text=' ', background_color=[0, 0, 0, 0], on_press=self.startcycle)
        fl.add_widget(buttonstart)
        global videostart
        videostart = Video(source='C:/PhotoBooth/animations/Start/TouchHereToStart.mov',  state='play', options={'allow_stretch': False})
        videostart.options = {'eos': 'loop'}
        fl.add_widget(videostart)
        return fl

    def startcycle(self, *arg):

        fl.remove_widget(buttonstart)
        fl.remove_widget(videostart)
        self.countdown = Video(source='C:/PhotoBooth/animations/Countdown/Countdown.mov',  state='play', options={'allow_stretch': False})
        self.countdown.options = {'eos': 'false'}
        fl.add_widget(self.countdown)
        return fl

    def takephoto(self):
        print("TESTING")

Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')
Config.set('graphics', 'rotation', 0)
MyPhotoBoothApp().run()
```

Comment: you haven't created a class instance that calls the function. do something like `myClassInstance = MyPhotoBoothApp()` then `myClassInstance.build()`. Also, you aren't passing in `App` that you've said your class needs.

Answer (score 2):

To call function you should use parentheses:

```
self.takephoto()
```